# Tribute was already bound to BODY Wysiwyg editor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg, froala

Using [Froala tribute js](https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/examples/tribute-js/)

**Error:- Tribute.js:159 Tribute was already bound to BODY**

When I am using froala fullPage..
And I have read the documentation as well and there is nowhere to mention this problem. The error is coming only when I am adding fullpage option and set it as true.
This is not helping me to figure to any solution.

[image]

```
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tributejs@3.5.3/dist/tribute.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/froala-editor@3.1.0/js/froala_editor.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/froala-editor@3.1.0/css/froala_editor.pkgd.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tributejs@3.5.3/dist/tribute.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h4> with Tribute </h4>
<div id="Not working with Tribute"></div>
<h4> withoutTribute </h4>
<div id="Working with Tribute"></div>
<script>

    var tribute = new Tribute({
        values: [
            { key: 'Phil', value: 'pheartman' },
            { key: 'Gordon', value: 'gramsey' },
            { key: 'Jacob', value: 'jacob' },
            { key: 'Ethan', value: 'ethan' },
            { key: 'Emma', value: 'emma' },
            { key: 'Isabella', value: 'isabella' }
        ],
        selectTemplate: function(item) {
            return '<span class="fr-deletaable fr-tribute">' + item.original.key + '</a></span>';
        }
    })

    new FroalaEditor('#withTribute', {
        fullPage: true,
        events: {
            initialized: function() {
                var editor = this;

                tribute.attach(editor.el)

                editor.events.on('keydown', function(e) {
                    if (e.which == FroalaEditor.KEYCODE.ENTER && tribute.isActive) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }, true);
            }
        }
    });

    new FroalaEditor('#withoutTribute', {
        fullPage: false,
        events: {
            initialized: function() {
                var editor = this;

                tribute.attach(editor.el)

                editor.events.on('keydown', function(e) {
                    if (e.which == FroalaEditor.KEYCODE.ENTER && tribute.isActive) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }, true);
            }
        }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: the issue is already in opened in github repository https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-editor/issues/3789